# Getting the error message 'org.apache.spark.SparkException: Couldn't find leader offsets for Set' in Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm running spark streaming. It was working fine for around 20 mins but then I got the below error message.

```
kafka.common.NotLeaderForPartitionException, org.apache.spark.SparkException: Couldn't find leader offsets for Set([lbs_avro,87], [lbs_avro,39], [lbs_avro,21]))
```

Could you please help me how to overcome this. I'm using createDirectStream API to consume the messages with the below parameters

```
"metadata.broker.list" -> kafkaBrokers, "group.id" -> kafkaGroupId, "auto.offset.reset" -> "largest", "enable.auto.commit" -> "true"
```

Thanks

Comment: Your Kafka leader node seems to be down. Could you check your cluster status?

Comment: I have checked the kafka cluster. All the brokers are up and running. Not sure what exactly is the issue. Thanks